# ProgressBar betweed activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two activities. The first one executes the second one.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyOne.this, MyTwo.class);
                     startActivity(i);
```

**The problem:** My second activity does some heavy work on launching so it launches couple of second and before it is launched i see a black screen.

Is it any way to set a progressbar or some image instead of this black screen? Because i don't think user will wait for something, that he doesn't know. I tried setting progressbar after *setcontentview* in my second activity, but progressbar shows up only when activity fully started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to do this asynchronously using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Short example:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                   dialog = ProgressDialog.show(...);
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            try {
               // doSomethingHeavy();
                   // publishProgress(...);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //...
            } 

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting "Variable 'dialog' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final". 
What is the right way to effect the Dialog (Activity scope) inside the Async Task Class?

Answer (score 1):

You sure can.  Check out the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask) for inspiration.