# Start activity after all its elements load

Tags: android, asynchronous

`Activity2` is started from `Activity1` via `StartActivity()` method. Activity2 has a lot of elements and it loads slowly. Because of that, Activity2 does not load instantly after it has been called, but first desktop appears for a second, and then Activity2 loads. This 1s gap is probably because of Activity2 slow loading.

How can I start Activity2 after all of its elements have been loaded? Should I use `StartActivityForResult` or something else?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "activity loads elements"?

Comment: Please post the XML-Layout of `Activity2`. Also, do you mean it loads Views or is it populating something like a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to have a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) that will be displayed while the activity gets loaded. You have to do the loading asynchronously (so that you don't block the main UI-thread) by using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You might be interested by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316232/progressbar-betweed-activities/6316261#6316261).

Answer (score 1):

you can override `public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)`. This method is called just as the window of the Activity becomes visible. If hadFocus == true, call your second Activity.